# Thread puzzle - waiting for thread from UI thread (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, infinite-loop

I have a weird chicken-and-egg type of problem:

I have a Task that takes images from a camera and puts them on the UI (WPF).
When I exit the app window, I want to shut down the camera properly, so I call Dispose(). BUT, the camera cannot shut down if there are images still in the buffer, so I have to wait for that thread to finish (I trigger the thread to stop by changing a "isLive" boolean).

BUT, the thread uses a Dispatcher from the UI to post the image. Calling "Wait()" on the thread from the UI thread makes it stall the UI thread, which in turn stalls the camera thread while it's trying to update the UI, making it hang indefinitely.

Below is a simple version of my code. Is there a trick to get around this?

```
public void GoLive()
{
    isLive = true;
    cameraTask = Task.Run(new Action(() =>
    {
        cam.BeginAcquisition();
        while (isLive)
        {
            var rawImage = cam.GetNextImage(); // gets raw img from camera buffer

            // now make image appear on my UI
            UIDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // this happens on the UI thread 
                uiImage = ConvertRawToBitmapSource(rawImage);
            }));
        }
}

// when you click to exit the window, this Dispose() method gets called:

public void Dispose()
{
    isLive = false; // a field boolean
    cameraTask.Wait(); // <------ hangs here infinitely!!!
    cam.DeInit(); // shut down the camera
}
```

Comment: Ok how are you changing the "isLive" flag.. otherwise its constantly trying to get next image

Comment: Are you aware that signalling with a bool like that will only work properly on a CPU with a strong memory model? That code won't work on a CPU with a weak memory model like an ARM7 unless you mark the bool as volatile and it still won't be reliable.

Comment: For sure, you should not wait in `Dispose()`. Unfortunately, your question offers very little information. Like, how will you know you've processed all the images in the buffer? Like, if you're shutting down, do you really need to pass an image to the UI thread? Like, have you ever heard of things like `async`, `await`, and `TaskCompletionSource`? There are just too many unknowns here, making the question too broad. You'll need to narrow it, including providing a good [mcve] showing exactly how the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simpy run the acquisition loop in the UI thread, and get each frame in a separate Task. Now all you need to do to stop is to set `isLive = false:`.

```
public async Task RunAcquisition()
{
    cam.BeginAcquisition();

    while (isLive)
    {
        var rawImage = await Task.Run(() => cam.GetNextImage());

        uiImage = ConvertRawToBitmapSource(rawImage);
    }

    cam.DeInit();
}
```

The camera might even have an awaitable `GetNextImageAsync` method, which would further simplify your loop:

```
public async Task RunAcquisition()
{
    cam.BeginAcquisition();

    while (isLive)
    {
        var rawImage = await cam.GetNextImageAsync();

        uiImage = ConvertRawToBitmapSource(rawImage);
    }

    cam.DeInit();
}
```

Comment: I only want to call DeInit() once when I exit the app, not every time I go out of LiveMode. I have a button that stops LiveMode simply by setting isLive = false which works fine. I ended up making my Dispose() function async and awaiting a while loop that checks if the camera is still streaming, using a function cam.IsStreaming(). Seems to work fine for now, whether this is good programming practice or not, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `UIDispatcher.Invoke` to `UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke` to avoid a synchronized call to the UI thread. Then, however, you need to make sure that the `rawImage` is still valid when the UI thread converts the image. Hence, the ownership of `rawImage` has to be moved to the Action object to avoid data races.